# How to start Architect and build the test infrastructure on Azure Cloud?

Tags: test-architecture, test-configration

I am working on a product, we are building a Mobile application for Android & iOS platform, In the first phase, we are planning to use some web services & serving process content to end user. My company want to set-up Test Environment & help to design the Architecture of backend design so that Testing team can manage the Test Environment on the cloud, frankly speaking, I am new to cloud technology as a Tester. Our product architect says that architecture will be different from the developer environment. So I need your help How can I start Architecture and building the test infrastructure on the Azure cloud as a tester?

Comment: What do you mean by " test team can manage the test environment on the cloud"?

Comment: Testing team will be responsible for test configuration & infrastructure. test team will take care of it.

Comment: Ideally test teams should be responsible for testing only , not for the configuration & management of  environments.

Comment: Although they may provide their inputs  if required.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more details, or come up with more specific questions over time. We don't even know what type of product do you have.
In the meanwhile I can add some points from experience, some of it is from AWS but the general ideas are the same.

Cloud Services are like Lego blocks for adult engineers, you can achieve things in many way by connecting different types of blocks.

For example if you need a CI server you can install Jenkins on a VM, use the Cloud's builtin solution or use something else like Lambdas. The same applies for deployment tools (CLI vs. SSH for example), databases (installed on a VM, pre-configured etc.)

What it means is that you need to start learning and get to know your platform, read, ask questions and try things out to find what best suites you- it's usually cheap and quick to hack a crude solution as proof of concept.

Security could limit your solution space, for example what can run where or when. Get to know the architecture and the reasoning behind it.

Finally remember to separate the Test version of the product (aka test environment) from the where the test code runs. For example if you are testing a web service you will need a test copy of the server, database and networking but also a server (or Lambda) that runs tests for you.

TLDR; do some homework, learn, test and ask then come back with more specific questions

Comment: Sorry @Rsf I know it is a very ambiguous, incomplete question but I can't disclose product information on a social platform, In general, We are building a Mobile application for Android & iOS platform, In the first phase, we are using some web services & serving process content to end user. what sort of resource is required to set up a working test infrastructure? Question updated

Comment: For your test product you would need the same things as your product, basically duplicate it and simplify if needed (a smaller DB for example). Some cloud provider provide virtual mobile device for testing, Azure might have xamarin devices available from the cloud, it's worth checking

Comment: They have given me the authority to decide the test configuration of the resource they want to know what testing team want and at this point, I am feeling blank from the test infrastructure point of view. I no voice on test infrastructure. I am not sure, where to start?

Comment: DevOps team is giving KT but I don't think so it's working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Go to portal.azure.com make a free account and start from there.

If your organisation has msdn licences then you may be on a plan that allows you to provision with some restriction.

I'd suggest you go look at plural sight or even youtube on videos on azure.